# How can I decode json data by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to show some data in my last div, but nothing happening.

I have no error.

**jquery:**

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: 'inc/show-date-delv.php',
        data: {"id": id},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('result');
            $(".dataandtime .date div:last-child").empty().append(obj.date);        
        }
});
```

**json (When I print `result` ):**

```
{"4":{"date":"\u06f2 \u062e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u06f9\u06f8"},"5":{"date":"\u06f3 \u062e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u06f9\u06f8"},"6":{"date":"\u06f4 \u062e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u06f9\u06f8"},"7":{"date":"\u06f5 \u062e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u06f9\u06f8"}}
```

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON('result')` is parsing the string `"result"`, not the variable

Comment: To clarify what @DBS already mentioned: Use `jQuery.parseJSON(result)` instead of `jQuery.parseJSON('result')`. Or even better (because this jQuery method is deprecated), use `JSON.parse(result)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can just use the built in JSON.parse(json)
Looking at your comment, if you get errors relating to your result. You can just do a console.log(result) and then be able to see if there are any errors in the json result

```
console.log(result)
var obj = JSON.parse(result)
```

Looking at the JSON `console.log()` result, you have "4", "5", "6" and "7", as the name container for the obj.
So you would need to do something like:

```
console.log(obj[4]["date"]); // Where 4 is the index you want
```

Also, not that its needed. [looking here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) it says that `JQUERY.parseJSON()` is deprecated

So full code would be something like :

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'inc/show-date-delv.php',
    data: {"id": id},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result){
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        for (var index in obj) {
            $(".dataandtime .date div:last-child").empty().append(obj[index]["date"]);
        }        
    }
})
```

Comment: obj.date nothing show for me.. How can I show date?

Comment: try doing obj["date"]

Comment: I can't use [4] because I don't know what is the number.

Comment: @alirezadarvishi Check edits. I assume you are wanting to append all of the dates to the html element? If not can you please update your question informing us of what data you want in the element as you have an object with multiple dates and we do not know what dates you are actually wanting to use.